# MiKTeX, constant Missing $ inserted. <inserted text> $ when using \neg

Tags: errors

I am very new at LaTeX that even I didn't even know till my teacher said all assignments required on LaTeX. I wrote my assignment but this error keep appearing. I am Mongolian so it is very difficult for me to understand what is really wrong. Please help.

```
111-р хуудас\\\

5.Given a conditional statement $p\rightarrow q$, find the converse
of its inverse, the converse of its converse, and the converse
of its contrapositive.\\\

inverse \neg p\rightarrow \neg q \\\
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You need to use `$` in the lower part as well. The double backslashes are also wrong. Please read [an introduction to LaTeX](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/). (<- Link to free ebook)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!! Could you please post an MWE to show enterely your problem?

Answer (score 1):

`\neg` needs to occur within math mode, so you need to use `$` to switch TeX into math mode, and `$` to switch out when your done.  Also, `\\` begins a new line.  If you want to double that up, it would be four of them: `\\\\`, but there are better ways to accomplish that.

```
111-р хуудас

\bigskip

5.Given a conditional statement $p\rightarrow q$, find the converse
of its inverse, the converse of its converse, and the converse
of its contrapositive.

\bigskip

inverse $\neg p\rightarrow \neg q$

\bigskip
```